# Why flexbox not working responsive design with flex-direction?

Tags: css, flexbox

i have doing my portfolio but i'm not good with CSS.

I'm using the Flexbox to do the design desktop and mobile but it not working...

It is like this, as i want, using `flex-direction: column`,:
[image]

Code of the div parent:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
background-color:#C4C4C4;
min-height: 100vh;
flex-direction: column;
```

But when i put in responsive, it stay like this:
The elements outside of div parent..
[image]

The code is the same, only changes the background-color.

```css
background-color: red;
width:800px;
height:650px;
margin: 30px;
```

It not stay corrects.

If i dont use the `flex-direction: column`, it stay like this:
[image]

Someone why?

Comment: Can you update your code snippet to include the HTML from your screenshots?

Comment: Yes, 1 minute, i have using React, i will try convert for you.

Comment: If you're having issues, feel free to at least just dump the code. A community member can edit your question and create a snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue was missing `max-width: 100%;` in the children so the `width:800px` would not overflow the container parent, take a look at the snippet

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(max-width:800px) {
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

div {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 650px;
  margin: 15px
}

div:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

div:last-of-type {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>red</div>
  <div>blue</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

max-width not set the width of the children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set a width to all of your containers; it looks like you want the gray container to fill the viewport, and the blocks to be evenly distributed.

Here's a working example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  min-height: 33vh;
  width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" style="background-color: red">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background-color: blue">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your snippet has horizontal scrollbar

Comment: also `space-evenly` is not widely support yet , see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=justify-content-space-evenly)